# git branch | grep '^SomeThingInFrontOfLine' not working

Tags: git, bash, grep, branch

I have a lot of git branches, I want to search only those begin with certain letters

i.e

```
$git branch
 branchA.abc.1234567
 branchA.cbc.1234457
 branchB.cbc.1234457.branchA.backup
 branchC.cbc.1234457.branchA.backup
```

And i want to only search those begin with 'brnachA'

```
$git branch | grep '^branchA'
```

But the above command returns nothing, any suggestions?

Comment: The lines don't start with "branchA" they start with spaces.

Comment: `git branch` also takes patterns directly so you shouldn't need grep here at all. `git branch branchA*`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, git version 2.1.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git branch` leaves spaces before the branch names to leave room for the current branch marker '*', so use any of:

- `git branch | grep '^. branchA'`
- `git branch | grep '^[^A-Za-z0-9]*branchA'`
- `git branch --list 'branchA*'`

Comment: `git branch --list 'branchA*'` is the best answer around here `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
git branch | grep '\bbranchA'
```

`\b` is *word boundaries*

Answer (score 1):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/yourpatternhere
```

For interactive use, a git alias might be good

```
git config --global alias.branches "git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)'"
```

and then

```
git branches|grep your_regexp_here
```